# Definition of geometric vector bundle from Hartshorne

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles

Hartshorne defines a geometric vector bundle as follows -

> Let $Y$ be a scheme. A *(geometric) vector bundle* of rank $n$ over $Y$ is a scheme $X$ and a morphism $f:X\rightarrow Y$ together with additional data consisting of an open covering $\{U_i\}$ of $Y$ and isomorphisms $\psi_i:f^{-1}(U_i)\rightarrow \mathbb A^{n}_{U_i}:=\text{ Spec }\mathbb Z[x_1,\cdots,x_n]\times_\mathbb Z U_i$ such that for any $i,j$ and for any open affine subset $V=\text{ Spec }A\subseteq U_i\cap U_j$ the automorphism $\psi = \psi_j\circ\psi_{i}^{-1}$ of $\mathbb A^{n}_{V} = \text{Spec }A[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$ is given by a *linear* automorphism $\theta$ of $A[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$, i.e, $\theta(a)=a$ for any $a\in A$ and $\theta(x_i)=\sum a_{ij}x_j$ for suitable $a_{ij}\in A$

I have the following question -

**Is it clear just from definition that if $U\subseteq U_i$ for some $i$ then $\psi_i(f^{-1}(U))=\mathbb A^n_U$?**

Comment: It should more or less be clear. The isomorphism $\psi_i$ is over $U_i$ so you're really asking whether the inverse image of $U$ in $\mathbb A^n_{U_i}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb A^n_U$ and it is. One way to see this is the following fact about Cartesian products: $(A \times_B C) \times_C D \simeq A \times_B D$.

Comment: @Hoot, could you elaborate a little? I don't get how the fact about Cartesian products can be used

Comment: I'm just translating like this: if $f\colon X \to Y$ is a morphism and $U \subseteq Y$ is open then $f^{-1}(U)$ is the same thing as $X \times_Y U$. I think he uses this in the construction of fiber products.

Comment: It might also be helpful to note that the isomorphisms $\psi_i$ is required to transform the map $f$ into the second projection $\mathbb{A}^n \times U \to U$. That is why restricting to a smaller subset of $U$ has the property you ask for.